# How to limit javascript popup for first three visits on a page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

How a javascript popup can be restricted to show on only first three visits for a page?

here is the html code

```html
<div id="vr-apper" style='display:none'>
    <div id="popup">
        <center>
             <!-- Content -->
            <input class="procced_pop_btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed" onClick="PopUp('hide')" />
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is javascript code to show popup

```html
<script>
    function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
    if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('vr-apper').style.display = "none";
    else document.getElementById('vr-apper').removeAttribute('style');
}
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        PopUp('show');
    }, 0);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Keep track of their visits and don't show it from their fourth visit onwards

Comment: You might want to look into cookies.

Comment: How to do this in wordpress pages?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using cookies that increments by 1 using incremention method **++** of JavaScript, and if the cookies value is 4 or above it won't show the popup!

Comment: Do you have any reference code to implement this for wordpress system?

Comment: No, I have never used Wordpress.